# Required String parameter 'userName' is not present

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to make an AJAX call from java script console as below

```
jQuery.ajax({
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: "/accountServices/resetPassword",
  type: "POST",
  data: '{
        "userName":"local_student",
        "newPassword":"test1231",
        "guid":"376ed5f7-a780-455e-8682-6b5cf45cff80"
         }'
});
```

And my controller method is something like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resetPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String resetPassword(@RequestParam("userName") String userName,
                            @RequestParam("newPassword") String newPassword,
                            @RequestParam("guid") String guid, Model uiModel, 
                            HttpServletRequest request, final Locale locale) 
                            throws MessagingException {
        try {}
}
```

I am getting the error

Required String parameter 'userName' is not present.

Could someone please help me out here!

Comment: Could you format your code (when you edit your question, there is a special button for it, `{}`)

Comment: `'{"userName":"local_student","newPassword":"test1231","guid":"376ed5f7-a780-455e-8682-6b5cf45cff80"}'` isn't a javascript valid object. replace it with `{userName:"local_student",newPassword:"test1231",guid:"376ed5f7-a780-455e-8682-6b5cf45cff80"}`

Answer (score 6):

you need to change your

```
data: '{
        "userName":    "local_student",
        "newPassword": "test1231",
        "guid":        "376ed5f7-a780-455e-8682-6b5cf45cff80"
       }'
```

**to**

```
data: {
        userName:    "local_student",
        newPassword: "test1231",
        guid:        "376ed5f7-a780-455e-8682-6b5cf45cff80"
      }
```

without

1. `'` before `{`
2. `"` while wrapping **userName**, etc.